# unrecognized selector for UITapGestureRecognizer in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using RxSwift and I want to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for dismiss keyBoard:

```
  let tapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapGest.rx.event.subscribe(onNext: {[weak self] _ in
        self?.view.endEditing(true)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGest)
```

but when I use gesture, app is terminating with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[*TtGC7RxCocoa13GestureTargetCSo22UITapGestureRecognizer* eventHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000446bd0'

Comment: Check my answer, and let me inform is any problem

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

I have see your problem and try to implement in my project. Based on this i have find out solution to do this. Hope this will also help you.

```
let tapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer()
 view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGest)

  tapGest.rx.event.bind { (recognizer) in
      self.view.endEditing(true)
  }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks , but not worked :(  ,  i use Xcode 9.0 beta 4, and RxSwift 4.0.0-alpha.0

Answer (score 0):

There are helper methods that put tap gestures onto views in RxCocoa. From there, you probably want to filter the gesture recognizer's state so you don't pick up all the events that don't matter. Something like:

```
view.rx.tapGesture()
    .filter { $0.state == .ended }
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        // Do something
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Was a bug in RxCocoa.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1382